# implementing multiplication feature in HugeInteger class

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, biginteger

I'm only showing what's relevant here.

**HEADER FILE:**

```
class HugeInteger
{
private:

static const int MAXDIGITS = 4;
int digits[MAXDIGITS];

public:

HugeInteger multiply(HugeInteger) const;
}
```

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

```
HugeInteger::multiply(HugeInteger op2) const
{

HugeInteger product, temp;

for(int numberB = MAXDIGITS -1, counter = 0; numberB >= 0; numberB--, counter++)
{
    int carry = 0;
    for(int numberA = MAXDIGITS -1; numberA >= 0; numberA--)
    {
        temp.digits[numberA-counter] = (op2.digits[numberB] * digits[numberA] + carry)%10;
        if(temp.digits[numberA-counter] >= 10)
        {
            carry = temp.digits[numberA-counter] / 10;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    product = product + temp;
}
return product;
}
```

and the **output** function looks like this:

```
void HugeInteger::output()
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAXDIGITS; i++)
    {
        cout << digits[i];
    }
}
```

Now this looks like it works but it doesn't. I'm almost there but I just can't get there. I've been working on this single function for 20+ hours but I don't think I'm smart enough to figure this out. Started all over again three times but just can't get it to work.

I'm trying to implement multiplication feature using a **HugeInteger** that is composed of arrays.

**edit: THIS (changed the place of the modulo) ends with the same result.**

```
HugeInteger HugeInteger::multiply(HugeInteger op2) const
```

{
    HugeInteger product, temp;

```
for(int numberB = MAXDIGITS -1, counter = 0; numberB >= 0; numberB--, counter++)
{
    int carry = 0;
    for(int numberA = MAXDIGITS -1; numberA >= 0; numberA--)
    {
        temp.digits[numberA-counter] = op2.digits[numberB] * digits[numberA] + carry;
        if(temp.digits[numberA-counter] >= 10)
        {
            carry = temp.digits[numberA-counter] / 10;
            temp.digits[numberA-counter] %= 10;
        }
        else
        {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    product = product + temp;
}
return product;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a carry bit you also need to take the modulus of the computed digit.

Comment: temp.digits[numberA-counter] = (op2.digits[numberB] * digits[numberA] + carry)%10;

        if(temp.digits[numberA-counter] >= 10)

isn't this what you mean??

Comment: yeah I think I did what you told me there

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to make it exceedingly clear just exactly what it is you are doing.

By moving the number shifting into the addition function, it makes the multiplication function more clear. Without dealing with the counter, it makes it clear that the function is just performing classic long multiplication.

```
//Add op2 to this.digits, but shift op2 by some amount of digits
//(The same thing as multiplying by 10^shift)
HugeInteger HugeInteger::add(HugeInteger op2, int shift) const{
    int carry = 0;
    HugeInteger ret = *this;
    for( int place = MAXDIGITS - 1; place >= 0; --place ){
        int value = carry;
        if( place >= 0 ){
            value += digits[place];
        }
        if( place + shift >= 0 && place + shift < MAXDIGITS ){
            value += op2.digits[place + shift];
        }

        ret.digits[place] = value % 10;
        carry = value / 10;
    }
    return ret;
}

HugeInteger HugeInteger::multiply(HugeInteger op2) const
{
    HugeInteger product, temp;
    int shift = 0;
    for(int numberB = MAXDIGITS - 1; numberB >= 0; numberB--)
    {
        int carry = 0;
        for(int numberA = MAXDIGITS -1; numberA >= 0; numberA--)
        {
            temp.digits[numberA] = op2.digits[numberB] * digits[numberA] + carry;
            if(temp.digits[numberA] >= 10)
            {
                carry = temp.digits[numberA] / 10;
                temp.digits[numberA] %= 10;
            }
            else
            {
                carry = 0;
            }
        }
        product = product.add(temp, shift++);
    }
    return product;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

i amnot smart enough either, but it looks to me that, in your function, you first take the module and then try to carry a number tht already got rid of... I think :/